# Building ONLY Labelled Versions with CruiseControl.net or TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, teamcity

We're currently using CruiseControl.NET as a continuous integration server for a number of ASP.NET web projects, but we're also evaluating TeamCity.

This is working great for our build server.

What we'd like to setup is a customer facing test server.  I'm thinking that when we are happy for our latest development version to be released to the client for test, we could label it in SVN.

I'd then like a second build server to build this version ready for the client to see.

The question is this - is there any way to get either CruiseControl.NET or TeamCity to build *only* the latest *labelled* version of the code in a repository?

If anyone has any alternative suggestions, that'd also be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a designated location or branch in your subversion repository e.g. \release then point the second TeamCity build server at that.

When your are happy with trunk then overwrite the existing location. The second build server will pick this up, build it, and even deploy it to a test server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this directly in TeamCity. You can however configure your build trigger to filter on files and/or users. So, if you touch a given file to indicate release status in addition to or rather than labelling, you can use that.

The trigger filter could be, for example (untested):

```
+:/ReleaseVersion.cs
```